# Tablelayout and Cursors

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-tablelayout

Is it possible to feed rows in a tablelayout from cursors? If yes, how?

My cursor.

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, countryName , capitalName FROM country WHERE countryName LIKE ?",new String[] { "%" });
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.capital_list_item,cursor, new String[] { "countryName" , "capitalName"},new int[] { R.id.countryName, R.id.capitalName });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly and sweetly, **No**.. You can't use Cursor Adapter in TableLayout

**You can use Cursor Adapter only in ListView, Spinner and GridView...**

Comment: basically all subclasses of AdapterView